# How to create a self-signed x509 certificate with both private and public keys?

Tags: single-sign-on, x509certificate, adfs2.0, saml-2.0

I am creating an SSO "proof of concept" using SAML2 and ADFS2 (IdP).  Log In is working fine, however ADFS2 is requiring that my Logout request be signed (with a private key) and then I would imagine that I would then add that very same certificate (.cer file) under the Signature tab within my Relying Party Trusts in ADFS2.  The only problem is that I don't have a certificate for my app (service provider).  I understand that I can create a self-signed cert for this purpose but I can't seem to figure out how to create one with everything I need.

Answer (score 26):

In order to generate a self-signed cert you need openssl library so:

Debian:
    `apt-get install openssl`

Centos/RedHat:
    `yum install openssl`

Then follow this 3 steps:

- Generate private key:

  `openssl genrsa -out server.pem 2048`
- Generate CSR: (In the "Common Name" set the domain of your service provider app)

  `openssl req -new -key server.pem -out server.csr`
- Generate Self Signed Cert

  `openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.pem -out server.crt`

At the end of the process you will get server.csr (certificate signing request), server.pem (private key) and server.crt (self signed cert)

In windows you can use [makecert.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: It seems that ADFS is requiring a .cer, .sst or .p7b file.  Are either of those possible with your solution?

Comment: You can use x509 cert for "Token-signing certificate" in ADFS 2.0:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd807040%28v=WS.10%29.aspx

The .pb7 is a cert file of the type application/x-pkcs7-certificates
To convert from the actual format (PEM or DER) to the pkcs7 format, you can execute:
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile server.crt -out server.p7b

 .The .sst files are in format application/vnd.ms-pki.certstore
Don't know how convert it with openssl

Comment: .crt and .pem are extension that I used.
You can rename them:
server.pem   to    server-private-key.cer
server.crt   to    server-self-signed-cert.cer

Comment: You can also use this online tool:
https://www.samltool.com/self_signed_certs.php

Comment: You can use `openssl req -new -x509 -key privateKey.pem -out cert.cer -days 365` to create a .cer format file from private key.

Comment: Is also important when generating the pivate key to do it to a robust alg, for example use the -sha512 option

Answer (score 3):

I used the SelfSSL tool for Windows when putting together an ADFS proof of concept. Specifically, this guy [has an enhanced version](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2010/04/16/setting-up-ssl-made-easy.aspx) for IIS7.

A sample command:

```
selfssl7.exe /N cn=www.example.com /K 2048 /V 3652 /X /F C:\example.pfx /W foo
```

Generates "example.pfx" file with a 2048-bit key, valid for ~10 years, with password "foo" protecting the private key, with common name "www.example.com". You can import this to your local machine's certificate store and then export it as a .cer file with or without the private key info as desired.

Comment: @Sean - And this cert will be able to be used as a way to sign (private key) a Single Log Out request (for example) sent over to ADFS in which ADFS uses the public key to verify?  Thanks so much.

Comment: Sean - When I go to export with private key, I don't get .cer as an option, only .pfx.  Is that normal?

Comment: @Brian Yes, that's normal. CER format cannot carry additional data like the private key. I believe PFX is more like a container format for lots of different kinds of security data, so it can handle bundling a certificate and key together.